# Set boolean value with SQL with Button click

Tags: vb.net

Currently im trying to when i select a row within a datagridview and then click a button it sets a Boolean field in an access database to be true, and nothing seems to be working

Here is my code

```
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Update Tbl_Rental Set @Collected = True Where CarID = @SelectedCarID "
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID", SelectedCarID)
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the call to actually update the database.
After `EndWith` add a new line `SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery`.

EDIT:

The parameter is @SelectedCarID, this is the name that should be used when adding the parameter.

```
If DbConnect() Then
    Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
    With SQLCmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "Update Tbl_Rental Set Collected = True Where CarID = @SelectedCarID "
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedCarID", SelectedCarID)
```

Comment: Ah i forgot that cheers but now i get a No value given for one or more required parameters error? Are my parameters correct?

Comment: @haz14 You shouldn't have the "@" in the column name "@Collected".

Comment: Is `CarID` a column in the table?  Try updating the update command to `Update Tbl_Rental Set @Collected = True Where CarID = @SelectedCarID` ie remove the @ in front of CarID.

Comment: Only the SQL parameters should be prefixed with @.  Column names should not be prefixed.

Comment: Nah it doesnt seem to work this is what it looks like now

Comment: You need to remove the @ before Collected too.  The update command should be `Update Tbl_Rental Set Collected = True Where CarID = @SelectedCarID`.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either could it be an issue with selecting the row??

Comment: I've done a break point and the Selected CarID seems to be 0 any reason for that??

Comment: Yes, that could be the issue. How are you selecting the car ID? Need to see more code to help.